# Update Facebook token for additional permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My application authenticates users via Facebook. It requests user token for permissions `public_profile` and `user_photos`.

One day I found that all registered users have only `public_profile`, and application have no access to their photos, because I did not get approve from Facebook for `user_photos` permission.

After all I got this approve, and tokens of new users logged in via Facebook have `user_photos` permission.

But legacy users have no, their tokens did not updated automatically to obtain additional `user_photos` permission.

Is there a way to refresh a Facebook token, without logout and login again?

Comment: _“their tokens did not updated automatically”_ - of course they didn’t, d’oh. Every user still has to decide for themselves, whether they want to grant that permission to your app or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can´t just refresh a Token without user interaction, that would make the whole point of permission authorization pointless. You can just check for the granted permissions and call `FB.login` (if using the JS SDK) again if some permission is missing: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/permissions/

This may be interesting for you too: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/handling-declined-permissions/

Comment: This might be useful as well: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/handling-declined-permissions/

Comment: thanx, added it to the answer